# Magento 2 RestAPI shows wrong stockid

Tags: magento2.3, rest-api

I ran the Magento Rest API to get the stock id for a particular product but it's showing me the wrong stock id. We have three websites and each website has a separate stock, but when we call Magento API for these three websites, the stock is shown the same for every product which is wrong. Can anyone please help me here as this is urgent for maintaining correct stocks for our website?

Please find below the result for the Magento Rest API

METHOD - GET

URL - http://127.0.0.1:8080/rest/kind_uk_en/V1/products/KIN30137

```
{

"stock_item": {
  "item_id": 1822,
  "product_id": 193,
  "stock_id": 1,
  "qty": 15,
  "is_in_stock": true,
  "is_qty_decimal": false,
  "show_default_notification_message": false,
  "use_config_min_qty": true,
  "min_qty": 1,
  "use_config_min_sale_qty": 1,
  "min_sale_qty": 1,
  "use_config_max_sale_qty": true,
  "max_sale_qty": 10000,
  "use_config_backorders": true,
  "backorders": 0,
  "use_config_notify_stock_qty": true,
  "notify_stock_qty": 1,
  "use_config_qty_increments": true,
  "qty_increments": 0,
  "use_config_enable_qty_inc": true,
  "enable_qty_increments": false,
  "use_config_manage_stock": false,
  "manage_stock": true,
  "low_stock_date": null,
  "is_decimal_divided": false,
  "stock_status_changed_auto": 0
}
}
```

Comment: Hey Ashish, later you got any solution for this? I am using Magento 2.4.3-p1 with MSI
I am facing this same issue and want stock based on what I assigned to that scope.
Please share if you got any solution, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using this endpoint instead `/rest/default/V1/stockItems/{productSku}` (just replace 'default' scope as you need) (Please refer to  https://magento.redoc.ly/2.4.2-admin/tag/stockItemsproductSku#operation/catalogInventoryStockRegistryV1GetStockItemBySkuGet for further details).

Comment: Hi , thanks for your help . We tried running the api with different scopes but it's still showing stock_id=1 .